# Enviar datos a BBDD desde un Form con PHP sin recargar la Web

Tags: php, html, mysql

```html
<form action="db_principal.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<textarea placeholder="En que estas pensando?" name="detalle" required=""></textarea>

<input id="coords" type="text" class="form-control" name="coords" value="input 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGmap" required=""/>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="input 2" required=""/>

<button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success green" name="publicar"></button>

</form>
```

Y este archivo PHP de prueba

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "coordenadas";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";

$coords = $_POST['coords'];
$detalle = $_POST['detalle'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO lugares (coords, detalle, titulo) VALUES ('$coords', '$detalle', '$titulo')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        header("Location: index.html");


} else {
      echo ", Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Lo que sucede es que si bien todo funciona perfectamente... Cuando le doy clic al botón de "publicar" se envían los datos a la BBDD pero me lleva al siguiente enlace `localhost/root/db_principal.php`. Si ven el código de `PHP` van a notar una parte que dice `header("Location: index.html");` Esto lo que hace es redirigir al usuario a la web `index.html`... Pero tampoco me sirve. Yo necesito que al hacer clic en "Publicar" Se ejecute `action="db_principal.php"` del `form` sin recargar la web. Vale considerar que esto sucede a través del método `POST`

Comment: necesitas implementar AJAX para hacer un envío de la información

Comment: Podrías generar un ejemplo para hacerme una idea? Muchas Gracias

Comment: Lo que necesitas se hace con AJAX, te dejo un video con un ejemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZdG0DTC4zc